# Timestamp to iso

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, iso

I have a `dataframe` with timestamp of different formats one with `05-28-2022 14:05:30` and one with `06-04-2022 03:04:13.002` both I want to convert into `iso` format how can I do that?

```
input                          output
05-28-2022 14:05:30     -> 2022-05-28T14:05:30.000+0000
06-04-2022 03:04:13.002 -> 2022-06-04T03:04:13.002+0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strptime() + strftime()`. Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# parse str to instance
first = datetime.strptime('05-28-2022 14:05:30', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
first = first.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
print(first.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
print(f'{first.isoformat()}')

second = datetime.strptime('06-04-2022 03:04:13.002', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
second = second.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
print(second.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
print(second.isoformat())

# 2022-05-28T14:05:30.000000+0000
# 2022-05-28T14:05:30+00:00
# 2022-06-04T03:04:13.002000+0000
# 2022-06-04T03:04:13.002000+00:00
```

See [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-datetime). Also you can use other packages for dates processing / formatting:

- [iso8601](https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/)
- [pendulum](https://pypi.org/project/pendulum/)
- [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)
- [arrow](https://github.com/arrow-py/arrow)

Example with `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz
from datetime import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['05-28-2022 14:05:30', '06-04-2022 03:04:13.002']})


def convert_date(x):
    dt_format = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f' if x.rfind('.', 1) > -1 else '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'
    dt = datetime.strptime(x, dt_format).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')


df['new_date'] = df['date'].apply(convert_date)
print(df)
                      date                         new_date
0      05-28-2022 14:05:30  2022-05-28T14:05:30.000000+0000
1  06-04-2022 03:04:13.002  2022-06-04T03:04:13.002000+0000
```